# Disable Semantic UI dropdown option being selected when tabbing to next element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard, accessibility, semantic-ui

I am working with ReactJS and using Semantic UI.

I have a breadcrumb style navigation menu on my page built using the 'Breadcrumb' and 'Dropdown' components from Semantic UI.

I am trying to make the behaviour of the menu accessible by allowing the user to use the keyboard (tab, arrows and enter) to navigate the menu, the dropdown options and to make a selection from the dropdown options.

The issue I am trying to solve is when using the keyboard, the user should only be able to select an option when it is focused on (using the arrow keys) **followed by pressing the 'enter' key**. At the moment when the user focuses on an option, it gets selected when they 'tab' to the next element.

Is it possible to change this behaviour so an option is only selected when the enter key is pressed?

I tried implementing *"selectOnNavigation={false}"* on the Dropdown component however this still results in the option being selected when 'tabbing' away from the element.

I also tried manipulating the event handler onBlur() but it still selected the option when tabbing.

Code for my component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Breadcrumb, Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  saveBreadcrumbOptions,
  changeBreadcrumbMarket,
  changeBreadcrumbParentGroup,
  changeBreadcrumbAgency
} from '../../actions/breadcrumbActions';
import MenuFiltersAPI from '../../api/MenuFiltersAPI';
import './OMGBreadcrumb.css';

export class OMGBreadcrumb extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      markets: [],
      parentGroups: [],
      agencies: []
    };

    this.getBreadcrumbOptions = this.getBreadcrumbOptions.bind(this);
    this.handleMarketChange = this.handleMarketChange.bind(this);
    this.handleParentGroupChange = this.handleParentGroupChange.bind(this);
    this.handleAgencyChange = this.handleAgencyChange.bind(this);
    this.handleParentGroupBlur = this.handleParentGroupBlur.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBreadcrumbOptions();
  }

  async getBreadcrumbOptions() {
    // get all options
    const breadcrumb = this.props.breadcrumb.options.length
      ? this.props.breadcrumb.options
      : await MenuFiltersAPI.getBreadcrumb();

    // if a market is selected, use it
    // otherwise use the first one
    let selectedMarket = breadcrumb.find(m => (
      m.id === this.props.breadcrumb.selectedMarket
    ));

    selectedMarket = selectedMarket
      ? selectedMarket.id
      : breadcrumb[0].id;

    this.props.saveBreadcrumbOptions(breadcrumb);
    this.setState({ markets: breadcrumb }, () => this.changeMarket(selectedMarket));
  }

  changeMarket(id) {
    // get parent group options for given market
    const parentGroups = this.state.markets.find(market => market.id === id).parent_groups;

    // if a parent group is selected, use it
    // otherwise use the first one
    let selectedParentGroup = parentGroups.find(pg => (
      pg.id === this.props.breadcrumb.selectedParentGroup
    ));

    selectedParentGroup = selectedParentGroup
      ? selectedParentGroup.id
      : parentGroups[0].id;

    this.props.changeBreadcrumbMarket(id);
    this.setState({ parentGroups }, () => this.changeParentGroup(selectedParentGroup));
  }

  changeParentGroup(id) {
    // get agency options for dropdown menu
    const agencies = this.state.parentGroups.find(parentGroup => parentGroup.id === id).agencies;

    let selectedAgency = agencies.find(a => (
      a.id === this.props.breadcrumb.selectedAgency
    ));

    selectedAgency = selectedAgency
      ? selectedAgency.id
      : agencies[0].id;

    this.props.changeBreadcrumbParentGroup(id);
    this.setState({ agencies }, () => this.changeAgency(selectedAgency));
  }

  changeAgency(id) {
    // const selectedAgency = agencyOptions[0].value
    this.props.changeBreadcrumbAgency(id);
  }

  handleMarketChange(e, { value }) {
    console.log(value)
    this.changeMarket(value);
  }

  handleParentGroupChange(e, { value }) {
    console.log(value)
    // if(!!value){
    //   return;
    // }
    this.changeParentGroup(value);
  }

  handleAgencyChange(e, { value }) {
    console.log(value)
    this.changeAgency(value);
  }

  handleParentGroupBlur(e, {value}) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.key)
    if(e.key !== 'Enter'){
      console.log('key was not enter')
      return;
    }
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="OMGBreadcrumb">
        <b>Show information by: </b>
        <Breadcrumb>
          <Breadcrumb.Section>
            <Dropdown
              selectOnNavigation={false}
              options={this.state.markets.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                acc.push({ text: cur.name, value: cur.id });
                return acc;
              }, [])}
              value={this.props.breadcrumb.selectedMarket}
              onChange={this.handleMarketChange}
              openOnFocus={false}
            />
          </Breadcrumb.Section>

          <Breadcrumb.Divider icon='right chevron' />

          <Breadcrumb.Section>
            <Dropdown
              selectOnNavigation={false}
              options={this.state.parentGroups.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                acc.push({ text: cur.name, value: cur.id });
                return acc;
              }, [])}
              value={this.props.breadcrumb.selectedParentGroup}
              onChange={this.handleParentGroupChange}
              openOnFocus={false}   
              onBlur={this.handleParentGroupBlur}         
            />
          </Breadcrumb.Section>

          <Breadcrumb.Divider icon='right chevron' />

          <Breadcrumb.Section>
            <Dropdown
              // selectOnNavigation={false}
              options={this.state.agencies.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                acc.push({ text: cur.name, value: cur.id });
                return acc;
              }, [])}
              value={this.props.breadcrumb.selectedAgency}
              onChange={this.handleAgencyChange}
              openOnFocus={false}
            />
          </Breadcrumb.Section>
        </Breadcrumb>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

OMGBreadcrumb.propTypes = {
  saveBreadcrumbOptions: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  changeBreadcrumbMarket: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  changeBreadcrumbParentGroup: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  changeBreadcrumbAgency: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  breadcrumb: PropTypes.objectOf(
    PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.number,
      PropTypes.array
    ])
  ).isRequired
};

export default connect(
  store => ({
    breadcrumb: store.breadcrumb
  }),
  {
    saveBreadcrumbOptions,
    changeBreadcrumbMarket,
    changeBreadcrumbParentGroup,
    changeBreadcrumbAgency
  }
)(OMGBreadcrumb);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: can you provide a sample or show us what have you done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `selectOnBlur={false}` to your dropdown component and it will no longer select when the dropdown is blurred.

```
<Dropdown
  ...
  selectOnBlur={false}
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-7qgcu?module=%2Fexample.js

Comment: Kicking myself for spending hours on this and not spotting it in the documentation